# Autofac MVVM - Lifetime

Tags: mvvm, dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac

Are there any examples of using Autofac in a MVVM application? I'm not sure how one would control lifetimes and disposal of objects in a MVVM environment.

I understand I can create a lifetime and resolve from beneath it, but that really seems more like a service locator pattern than an IoC pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a public example, but I have done this in Silverlight applications.

I used the [Silverlight navigation framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to organize the top level of content. When the frame navigated to a new page, I created a lifetime scope in which I resolved the page's root view model, which I associated with the page through an attribute:

```
[ViewModel(typeof(OrdersViewModel))]
public class OrdersView : Page
```

When the frame navigated to a different page, I disposed the lifetime scope before creating the next one.

The same pattern applies to opening dialogs. Each dialog gets its own lifetime scope and view model. When it closes, the lifetime scope gets disposed.

There are also situations which don't fall neatly along these boundaries. Sometimes you need more granularity and can go deeper into lifetime scopes using [contextual scopes](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/InstanceScope). These situations are usually one-offs and involve some glue to begin the lifetime scopes.

I find it helpful to think in terms of [units of work](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/unitOfWork.html): you commit changes at the end of each lifetime scope. This makes the [extent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_%28programming%29#Scope_and_extent) of a set of data a natural lifetime scope.

Comment: The source code available at http://code.google.com/p/whitebox/ demonstrates something like this - using navigation to mark unit of work boundaries. It mightn't make a very clear example because of a lot of extra noise, but SessionViewModel and ApplicationModule might provide some clues.

Comment: Paul Stovell's also posted some initial details on achieving this with Magellan - hopefully there's more to come in this series :) http://www.paulstovell.com/unit-of-work

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answers. I'll look into some of these options. Whitebox looks awesome btw, I was just thinking that an IoC profiler would be very handy...